# Adding a class to what has changed in .map()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently having some really difficulties in finding out how to updated an array of over 200 countries with data. What I want to do is on change add class to the countries that have updated, countries may go up or down as well so they may change position so I cant use the index and compare that way.

I am currently updating the value with state and then calling the api and setting that date to the state and the map will re-render. However it needs to add a class to those where the value has changed and may be in a new order the list.

Comment: please add some code so we better understand your issue

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment because I don't have enough **SO** influence points so I'll try out to answer based on some assumptions:

- You receive the countries from the API and store them in the state;
- You don't have a flag like `updated: true`

What I would do based on your explanation and my understanding of it is:

- Once I update the country I'll add an updated flag
- I will make each country a component, passing that flag downwards. Then, according to that flag, I will be applying the desired class like this - `updated ? updatedClass : normalClass`

If for some reason you receive the countries with something like:

```
{
   countryCode: "PT", 
   createdDate: "someDate", 
   updatedDate: "someDate"
}
```

I would compare the createdDate with the updatedDate and see if there were differences. If there were, I'll just add the updated flag before storing them in the state and do the thing the same way as explained before.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Only just came back but came to the same conclusion that passing an update date would be the only way that I could thing off. I am still wondering though if there is any other way other than the api returning the update.

Comment: I would say this is the best way since you have power over the API and also thinking about cost/benefit. If this is the correct answer please mark it as such ;)